# How can I create a loop to merge two DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames:

| name | age | weight | sex | d_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| john | 21 | 56 | M | futboll |
| martha | 25 | 43 | F | soccer |
| esthela | 29 | 53 | F | judo |
| harry | 18 | 72 | M | karate |
| irving | 24 | 61 | M | karate |
| jerry | 21 | 56 | M | soccer |
| john_2 | 26 | 69 | M | futboll |
| malina | 22 | 53 | F | soccer |

And

| d_type | impact | founds_in |
| --- | --- | --- |
| futboll | high | federal |
| soccer | medium | state |
| judo | medium | federal |
| karate | high | federal |

At the end I want a DF like this.

| name | age | weight | sex | d_type | impact | founds_in |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| john | 21 | 56 | M | futboll | high | federal |
| martha | 25 | 43 | F | soccer | medium | state |
| esthela | 29 | 53 | F | judo | medium | federal |
| harry | 18 | 72 | M | karate | high | federal |
| irving | 24 | 61 | M | karate | high | federal |
| jerry | 21 | 56 | M | soccer | medium | state |
| john_2 | 26 | 69 | M | futboll | high | federal |
| malina | 22 | 53 | F | soccer | medium | state |

How can I do this in pandas? I need a loop or it's better try in Linux?

Comment: Please check it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101, it's just a merge with `left` method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: is it r or python ?what it has to do with linux? remove unrelated tgs

Comment: `df1.merge(df2, on="d_type")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['john', 'martha'],
                    'age': [21, 25],
                    'd_type': ['futbol', 'soccer']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'d_type': ['futbol', 'soccer'],
                    'impact': ['high', 'medium'],
                    'founds_in': ['federal', 'state']})
df1.merge(df2, on = 'd_type').set_index('name')
```

which gives:

| name | age | d_type | impact | founds_in |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| john | 21 | futbol | high | federal |
| martha | 25 | soccer | medium | state |